# X3 Sector/Universe Traders: What do they do with existing cargo?

Tags: x3-albion-prelude

I have a chain of trader training going on where they start out as sector traders then once they hit level 15 or so I move them into a better ship using the "Move Pilot into New Ship" command and turn them into Universe Traders. Sometimes when it's convenient to do the switch, the trader I want to move has a cargo hold full of cargo it was intending to sell. I don't want to wait because often times it will end up buying more cargo at the same station after unloading. What I'd like is for the new pilot to simply resume selling whatever cargo is in the hold. I also want it to hold on to any required items such as fighter drones, energy cells for jumping, etc.

I'm a little unsure about how the script handles existing cargo. I believe I've read before (it would've been years ago) that any cargo in the hold when you issue the Start Sector Trader command is locked and will be left there. To avoid this I've been using Remote Best Sell... after switching out the pilot but that's very labour intensive and sometimes incredibly frustrating as the trader misses deal after deal.

So, is this true? What's the best strategy for dealing with it, if so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sector and Universe Traders will ignore existing cargo (with the exception of energy cells, which they will eventually use up for jumps, and fighter drones, which will serve as replacements for the drones the trader would normally acquire), reducing their effective cargo capacity. You will need to get rid of the excess cargo in some way, perhaps selling it as you were, dumping it into a storage ship or jettisoning it.